# can't access the class from ActionBar-PullToRefresh library

Tags: android, android-studio, pull-to-refresh, android-actionbar-compat

I'm on a android project and I need import the ActionBar-PullToRefresh library, so I import the library with gradle like following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
}
```

Then I `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, so I can use the `PullToRefreshLayout` in my layout xml file.But when I use the library's class in my Fragment code,I can't get nothing code trigger. When I spell the whole class name `PullToRefreshLayout` the Android studio will not import the class automatically. So what's the problem.

The next two file is my build.gradle file in the root directory and my app directory:

**build.gradle file in the root directory**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle file in the app directory**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ifeve.ifeveforandroid"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0') {
        force = true
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
}
```

Comment: ChrisBanes PullToRefresh is deprecated. I recommend using **SwipeRefreshLayout** from Google:  
[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)  
[Example](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

Comment: @MartinCR Yeah but SwipeRefreshLayout does not support adding hint "Pull to refresh" over ActionBar - that is the reason why I am using this library too.

Comment: Also G+ is also in ChrisBanes pull2refresh style. I don't like SwipeRefreshLayout touch "bounce" effect too.

Comment: @MartinCR Yeah, I try SwipeRefreshLayout but I can't get my ideal effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing library this way, add in **dependencies** section this line:

```
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.9'
```

Comment: I need the actionbar-compact support.I can't just import the library without actionbar-compact support.

Comment: I am using abs support and I use that line above and It works for me. Try It.

Comment: don't need add actionbar-compact support? just one line?